# Scala compilation error- found : Int required: Int => Int

Tags: scala, function, literals, function-literal

I am new to scala. I don't understand the compilation error for the below code:

```
def delayed( t:(Int)=> Int):Unit={
    println("In delayed method")
    var y=t; 
    println(y)
}

def time(x:Int):Int={
    x*2
}
```

and when I call

```
delayed(time(8))
```

I get the following error:

```
scala> delayed(time(8))
<console>:15: error: type mismatch;
found   : Int
required: Int => Int
delayed(time(8))
        ^
```

Please explain what is the issue? Please also suggest a good link to understand functions and function literals in scala. I am not able to understand fully.

Thanks so much

Edit:

Please tell the difference between

```
        def delayed( t: Int => Int):Unit = {
```

and

```
        def delayed(t: =>Int):Unit {
```

and

```
        def delayed(t:=>Int):Unit { (without space b/w ":" and "=>"))
```

Comment: you probably just meant `def delayed(t: => Int):Unit` which means `t` has type `Int` but it's a **call by name** argument, which means it only gets evaluated when used inside the method body, and not when method is _called_. What you did is different - as answered below, `t` is not an `Int` but a function `Int => Int`

Comment: I think you should ask this in another question. If you change the question, all the answers below become invalid.

Comment: Sorry @ntlabs. I have asked another question. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your function `delayed` expects function as an argument, however, you passed `Int`. That's why you get the error.

The type of the argument of `delayed` is `Int=>Int`, which means it is a function accept one `Int` as an argument and returns `Int`.

Your function `time` is `Int=>Int` function, however, when you pass `time(8)` to the `delayed` function, `time(8)` will be evaluated before it is passed to `delay`, and the evaluation result is just an `Int`.

```
scala> delayed(time(8))
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int
 required: Int => Int
       delayed(time(8))
                   ^
```

If you pass the `time` function only, it will work.

```
scala> delayed(time)
In delayed method
<function1>
```

If you want to pass `time(8)` as a function argument, you should change `time` function to return function:

```
scala> def time(x:Int) = () => x*2
```

You also need to modify `delayed` function like the below:

```
def delayed(t:()=>Int) {
    println("In delayed method")
    var y=t();
    println(y)
}
```

Then you can pass `time(8)` to `delayed`.

```
scala> delayed(time(8))
In delayed method
16
```

Or you can use *call by name* as @Tzach mentioned in the comment.

```
scala> def delayed(t: =>Int) {
     |   println("In delayed method")
     |   var y = t
     |   println(y)
     | }
delayed: (t: => Int)Unit

scala> def time(t:Int) = t*2
time: (t: Int)Int

scala> delayed(time(8))
In delayed method
16
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But, is there a way I can pass time function in delayed function without it being evaluated before? Can you pls tell the syntax to do the same.

Comment: How can I pass an argument to the time method?

Comment: Thanks for such an informative reply. One more thing, please, as you wrote def delayed(t: =>Int) , the code works but if I do not give a space b/w ":" and "=>", the code fails giving a compilation error. Does the space indicate something? Can you please tell what does the arguments in this line means- def delayed(t: =>Int)? Does this mean that there is a function which will be passed in delayed which can have any number of arguments and which returns an Int? Can it be used for any number of argument or can we specify a particular no. of argument for the function which we will pass? Thnks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Method `delayed` expects a function with Input param `Int` and return type `Int`
But in your example you are passing result of `time` function.

This will solve your issue.

```
delayed(time)
```